# Can csr certificate be generated in nonssl apache

Tags: csr

I am using apache2.2 nonssl .How to generate a csr certificate in that

Answer (score 3):

A CSR is not Apache dependent. You need OpenSSL or OpenTLS to create the CSR, and after you will put the result certificate (signed by the authority) in your Apache server.

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.csr -nodes -subj /C=FR/O=COMPANY/CN=server.domain.tld` permits to create the private key and the csr. Give the content of CSR file to your AC, and you will receive the cert file need to Apache.